# In jquery, how to get by class, but ignore if it contains another class?

Tags: jquery

I am currently doing this:

var blah = $(".blah");

And this works how I want 99% of the time, but in one page I want this to be ignored.

Is it possible to add 'unless' or 'ignore if contains xxx class' also?

Meaning, get me all dom elements that contain the class 'blah', but only if it doesn't contain the 'ignoreme' class also?

```
<div id="blah ignoreme"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`:not` filter selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
var blah = $(".blah:not('.ignoreme')");
```

Or using [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method:

```
var blah = $(".blah").not('.ignoreme');
```